# Rails 4 nested where clause on joined table that has multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, where-clause

I have an Order model that has TWO associations to a VoyageLeg Model (which then belongs to a Port) as below:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :boarding_leg, class_name: "VoyageLeg"
  belongs_to :disembarking_leg, class_name: "VoyageLeg"
end

class VoyageLeg < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :port
  has_many :orders_boarding, class_name: "Order", inverse_of: :boarding_leg, :foreign_key => 'boarding_leg_id'
  has_many :orders_disembarking, class_name: "Order", inverse_of: :disembarking_leg, :foreign_key => 'disembarking_leg_id'
end
```

I can do a where clause for the port on the `boarding_leg` like this:

```
Order.joins(boarding_leg: :port).where(ports: {code: "AKL"}).count
```

But how can I do a where clause for one port code on the boarding_leg and a different port code on the disembarking_leg??

when I do this:

```
Order.joins(boarding_leg: :port).where(ports: {code: "ALK"}).joins(:disembarking_leg).where(ports: {code: "WLG"}).count
```

the resulting SQL is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "voyage_legs" ON "voyage_legs"."id" = "orders"."boarding_leg_id" AND "voyage_legs"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "ports" ON "ports"."id" = "voyage_legs"."port_id" AND "ports"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "voyage_legs" "disembarking_legs_orders" ON "disembarking_legs_orders"."id" = "orders"."disembarking_leg_id" AND "disembarking_legs_orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "ports"."code" = 'ALK' AND "ports"."code" = 'WLG'
```

So it will never return anything as the port code cannot be both WLG and AKL - I need a way to have the where clause specific to the join.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there is a simple way to do this in ActiveRecord. Depending on which DB you are using you may need to do a subquery or write the conditions into the join clause.

Comment: I would try asking the same question but posing it as a pure SQL question (rather than rails specific) and adding the mysql or postgres tag as they tend to get much better answers. Just create a basic outline of the tables and what the desired result is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research to see if I can write as SQL - its a postgres DB by the way

Comment: You want to do it in a single query only?

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do (as suggested by @max) was to write more as SQL. I created an alias for the joins, and then I can reference the specifc join to alias the ports joins, and then reference the specific port as below:

```
Order.joins('INNER JOIN voyage_legs boarding_legs ON boarding_legs.id = orders.boarding_leg_id AND boarding_legs.deleted_at IS NULL INNER JOIN ports boarding_ports ON boarding_ports.id = boarding_legs.port_id AND boarding_ports.deleted_at IS NULL INNER JOIN voyage_legs disembarking_legs ON disembarking_legs.id = orders.disembarking_leg_id AND disembarking_legs.deleted_at IS NULL INNER JOIN ports disembarking_ports ON disembarking_ports.id = disembarking_legs.port_id AND disembarking_ports.deleted_at IS NULL').where('boarding_ports.code = :boarding_code AND disembarking_ports.code = :disembarking_code', boarding_code: "AKL", disembarking_code: "WLG").count
```